# I have a Type but need help on creating generic Func

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have an object **myClassType** of Type

```
string typeName = @"MyCompany.MyApp.MyDomain.MyClass";
Type myClassType = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

and I want to create a lambda expression (similar to the one below), but how do I get the **MyClass** from the **myClassType** so that I can pass it to the Func

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>()
```

Is it possible to do so? any alternative ways or suggestions welcome.

Comment: so do you need an object from `myClassType` type definition? Then use `Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType)` and cast it to `MyClass`. Notice there is an inconsistency: you have one type defined in two different ways: in string and in usual way as Type parameter

Comment: Would the result from Activator.CreateInstance(myclassType) can be used in Func<????, bool> ?

Comment: I am not looking to create an instance object of that type, but to use that type myClassType to create a Func<**MyClass**, bool>

Comment: Are you wanting to create an `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>` or just a `Func<MyClass, bool>`?

Comment: Actually I want to create Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(...)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Expression.Lambda(...)
```

Non generic signature and treat the result as your known type.